# Gitlab outsite project member able to push repository

Tags: git, gitlab

We curious with one of our developer than can still doing push to one of our branch that her username not listed on our project member. How she can do that?

We have set that project to `private mode` and she use different username and  easily push. 
[image]

[image]

What We missed here? Please see our configuration bellow.

[image]

We have been looking for any source on internet regarding this case and we think all we done are correct.

Comment: Do you have any deploy keys with write privileges set up?

Comment: As we know we don't use keys but where we can check that configuration?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#deploy-keys